# Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary in Swift?

Tags: swift, string, swift4

If I have the following as a `String`, how can I turn it into a `Dictionary` in Swift 4?

`{"cover_image":"CI","profile_image":"PI","github":"","location":"Somewhere between the north pole and the south pole","name":"R","website":"mysitesucksyoudon'twannavisititrightnow.imforreal","about":"Yeah, I'm a human."}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `JSONSerialisation` method `class func jsonObject(with data: Data, options opt: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = []) throws -> Any`:

```
let str = """
{"cover_image":"CI","profile_image":"PI","github":"","location":"Somewhere between the north pole and the south pole","name":"R","website":"mysitesucksyoudon'twannavisititrightnow.imforreal","about":"Yeah, I'm a human."}
"""
let dict = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(str.utf8))) as? [String:String] ?? [:]

print(dict)  // ["name": "R", "location": "Somewhere between the north pole and the south pole", "website": "mysitesucksyoudon\'twannavisititrightnow.imforreal", "github": "", "cover_image": "CI", "about": "Yeah, I\'m a human.", "profile_image": "PI"]
```

Comment: I'd recommend using Codable instead